# Cant run additional python script after calling run on flask app?

Tags: python

I was trying to do the following:

```
import webbrowser
app = Flask(__name__)
...

host = "0.0.0.0"
port = 9991
print "running app."
app.run(host=host, port=port)
print "about to open browser"
webbrowser.open("http://localhost:%s" % port)
```

and when I do this, it will not carry out the print statement after the `run` so i never see the print statement, nor does the browser open.

What do i do to handle this?  Subprocess?

Comment: yes, think of the `app.run()` as a `while(1)` use a thread or process to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: I didnt look at the inner content of run, but was making an educated guess that it created some sort of loop.  I guess maybe I should create a subprocess for app.run() and then call the webbrowser.open after a few seconds (wait a bit for the server to init)

Comment: you should be calling the `print` in a separate process and not the `app.run()`

Comment: @pyjg Why? `print` isn't blocking, so why should that be a problem?

Comment: well, try to do it your way, I dont think for sanity a different subprocess should be calling `app.run` but I might be wrong.

Comment: My thought process was "If the browser starts before the server is set up, the webpage is dead, so i should launch the server and confirm it is alive before opening the browser"  I guess that is why i was trying to do it my way.  It seems that launching the browser and then starting the server works, but i was not sure if there was a fringe case that would cause issues.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of how you would pass the `app` to the subprocess. Seems like passing the `app` might not be the best idea and I dont know how to do that off the top of my head so I was a bit cautious with your approach. Anyway, I guess if it works for you then it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do something like:

```
print "Opening browser..."
webbrowser.open("http://localhost:%s" % port)
print "Running app..."
app.run(host=host, port=port)
```

Flask servers usually start up quickly,
 so there should be no problem. However, if there is a "server not found" sort of problem reported by the browser, try the following:

```
import subprocess, time
print "Opening browser in 3 seconds..."

subprocess.Popen(['python', '-c', 'import time, webbrowser; time.sleep(3); webbrowser.open("http://localhost:%s")' % port])
print "Running app..."
app.run(host=host, port=port)
```

Comment: this works for me.  My thought was "What happens if the browser navigates to the endpoint before the server is properly set up."  That's why I was trying to launch the server before opening the browser.

Comment: @Fallenreaper Then you should start a subprocess for the `webbrowser` and add some delay.

Comment: @Fallenreaper I've added subprocess delay to the answer. Do let me know your thoughts :)

Comment: I like it.  Thanks

Comment: I like it.  Thanks.  The only thing I have noticed at the moment is that as of the subprocess, for some reason now this main function executes twice.  I dont really see why though

Comment: @Fallenreaper Which main function?

Comment: Im not sure why, but when I run the application, it launches this codebase twice (this is the content of the main function), which opens 2 browsers and 2 flask apps.  I dont think it is a subprocess issue though.